# What is the best way to get user's currency on an android device?

Tags: android, location, locale, currency, currency-formatting

I'm trying to build an app where users can enter prices of products according to their own country's currency (with the currency's symbol attached to an EditText), and then upload the values to a database. 
I've already tried the default Locale class but it uses the user's configuration so people like me, using US English on their devices outside the US, can enter only values in US dollars. Also, getting the information from the SIM card is not useful in some cases. How do apps like eBay or even the Play Store get this information? The only thing I can come up with is using the device's GPS. If so, how to extract the information? And if not, what should I do?

Comment: You can detect the currency by detecting the user's language. I think using the GPS is not an appropriate way to do it.

Comment: @CyprienAubry I know many people in my country, for example, that use English because it's more convenient. And still, most of the apps we use which are related to money can determine the currency apart from the language.

Comment: Okay, maybe you can correlate several informations such the user language with the Google Profile or the GPS position.

Answer (score 3):

Checking the sim card may be a good idea

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);    
Currency.getInstance(new Locale("", telephonyManager.getNetworkCountryIso()));
```

I'm living in the EU but using US-Locale for my smartphone because I prefer English. The code is giving me the EUR currency